# input to third party iphone app from another app or url

Tags: iphone, ios

**i want to populate few fields in third party iphone apps with the desired values.
is there any way i can achieve this.**
Can a CORE DATA file be used for this.

Answer (score 1):

Each app is run in its own private environment, so no two apps can interact with each other.  This is by design and necessary for security/consistency/etc reasons.

Check out these Apple [RuntimeEnvironment Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, but only if the 3rd party app has been run before yours on the same device, and has registered a custom URL handler for the purpose of populating fields.  Or perhaps if the app downloads these fields over the network from a server with a public API for configuring the fields.

Not otherwise, as the iOS security sandbox will prohibit this communication between apps.